# iOS Developer Program

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

Our scenario is:

- We will develop more than 10 apps with our client's logo and server connectivity urls one for each client.
- We will deploy these 10 apps to 10 different web server one for each client(Companies)
- Registered end user of each Company will download app from their web server.

My question is:
    1. can we do it with  iOS Developer Enterprise Program with ad hoc distribution

Answer (score 0):

i think that this might help. i have just come across it
http://diaryofacodemonkey.ruprect.com/2011/03/18/ad-hoc-app-distribution-with-xcode-4/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an enterprise license will solve your problem. But since the app is being deployed for 10 different companies, each company should have the app build using their one certificates and profiles.

Comment: Is it legal if I share distribution provisioning profiles with companies.

Comment: Actually with your provisioning profile, you are supposed to distribute apps only to employees of your enterprise and not other companies. That would be a license violation.

Comment: @Vin Where did you find this?

Comment: @Kai this is in the enterprise license agreement.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing things up a little.

AdHoc distribution is limited to 100 devices and is only available for the standard developer program. The standard developer program also is the only one allowing you to distribute apps via iTunes.

Enterprise distribution is unlimited in number of devices. The the devices do not even have to be registered within the profile. But you are not allowed to distribute anything outside of your company - not even for testing purposes.

From Apple's own [support pages](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enterprise.html):

> What are the primary differences between the Standard, Enterprise, and
>   University Programs?
>
> The standard individual and standard company programs are intended for
>   developers who create free and fee-based iOS apps for distribution on
>   the App Store.
>
> The iOS Developer Enterprise Program is intended for companies who
>   create proprietary, in-house iOS apps for internal deployment within
>   the company only. A valid Dun & Bradstreet (D-U-N-S) number is
>   required for program enrollment.
>
> The iOS Developer University Program is a free program designed for
>   higher education institutions looking to introduce curriculum for
>   developing iOS apps.

Comment: Would it be legal if I deploy all these different app on our own web server and all other end user download it from our server?

Comment: You may only give access to an App Distributed under the Terms of the Enterprise program to employees of your company.